# How to prove this equality with respect to Gamma function?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^u}\,dx = \frac{1}{u}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

How to prove this equality and what is the name of it?

Comment: Make the substitution $ \frac{1}{1+x^{u}} = t$ and then work with Beta- and Gamma integral relation

Comment: Have you got any ideas? You should look up Euler integrals (known also as Gamma and Beta functions)

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks, TheOscillator.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z:=\frac{1}{x^u+1}$, then $x^u=\frac{1-z}{z}$. Rewrite the integral in terms of $z$.